# Okhttp: Adding unencrypted custom headers in for Proxy server on https requests

Tags: java, okhttp

We are using okhttp v3.8.0 in our project. We have to add custom header specifically for proxy server on https requests. The issues is that when i set ".header("Something", "FRR")", header would be encrypted on https requests as well, so it would not be identified by Proxy server. How can I achieve that? I want to send the header unencrypted in Initial method. 
That's how I send my request to proxy server right now:

```
OK_HTTP_CLIENT = builder
    .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .cookieJar(cookieJar)
    .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
    .proxy(proxy)
    .proxyAuthenticator(proxyAuthenticatorMainAccount)
    .build();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url(url)
    .header("Something", "FRR")
    .build();

Response response = OK_HTTP_CLIENT.newCall(request).execute();
```

[There is screenshot here, explain what i want to achieve in more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZwGS.png)

Comment: @SLaks I just edit my post and attach a screenshot which explain what I want to achieve in more details, I was wondering if you could have a look at it

Comment: That might not be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possibly in OkHttp currently. It's being tracked [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2435). If it's important to you, please explain your situation and we’ll respond accordingly.

Comment: we have to send request to proxy server and saying Ip address of which country we are going to use for that specific request and this will only be possible by setting "country" header in the request,. As i said, it is working on http request but on https requests, proxy server could not identify the header as it is encrypted for destination. Is it possible to do it in other libraries? or even by HttpUrlConnection?

Comment: The easiest workaround is to fork OkHttp and add your headers in the RealConnection code when connecting the proxy.